# I am using two tables from database and to display on a page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to make a page which has to get data from two tables. and display on a page. this displayed data is an array. for example if the displayed data is say USA which come from Table A,and if you click on USA...then it should go to Table B and get all the states from Table B related to USA and display it on the page. so how to join the tables?
the code used is as below:

```
<?php
require("libs/config.php");
$pageDetails = getPageDetailsByName($currentPage);
$stateDetails = getStateDetailsById($page_id);

include("header.php");
?>
<div class="row main-row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <section class="left-content">
            <h2><?php echo stripslashes($pageDetails["page_title"]); ?></h2>
            <?php echo stripslashes($pageDetails["page_desc"]); ?>
            <!--New-->
            <?php
                $page_id = $pageDetails["page_id"];
                if ($_GET["id"] <> "")
                {
                    // if we are on page.php page. get the parent id and fetch their related subpages
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PAGES . " WHERE status = 'A' AND parent = :parent ORDER BY sort_order ASC";    
                    try
                    {
                        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);        
                        $stmt->bindValue(":parent", db_prepare_input($pageDetails["parent"]));
                        $stmt->execute();                
                        $pageResults = $stmt->fetchAll();              
                    }
                    catch (Exception $ex)
                    {
                        echo errorMessage($ex->getMessage());
                    }
                }
                elseif ($page_id <>"")
                {
                    // On any other Page get the page id and fetch their related subpages
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PAGES . " WHERE parent = :parent";
                    try
                    {
                        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindValue(":parent", db_prepare_input($page_id));
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $pageResults = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    }
                    catch (Exception $ex)
                    {
                        echo errorMessage($ex->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-12">     
            <?php
            if (count($pageResults) > 0)
            {
            ?>
                <section>
                <h2>States</h2>
                <div>
                <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($pageResults as $rs)
                { ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul class="state">
                            <li class="state">
                            <div class="state-dist"><h3><?php echo stripslashes($rs["page_title"]);?></h3>
                            <div class="state_img"><img src="images/<?php echo stripslashes($rs["page_image"]);?>"height="50" width="180"</div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <div class="page-actions">          
                            <a href="page1.php?id=<?php echo easy_crypt($rs["page_alias"]); ?>" class="btn btn-cta txt-center js-enroll-btn ">More Details</a>    
                            </div>  
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        <?php } ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

So,
when i click on the link created by the last part of the code then it should go to TABLE.STATES fetch the records and display it. Currently this code goes to the same table TABLE_PAGES.
I know i have to use table joins but I am not able to code it.

Comment: Can you state clearly which tables do you have and which you would like to join.

Comment: TABLE_PAGES AND TABLE_STATES  and TABLE_PAGES.page_id = TABLE_STATES.page_id
so, the result is 4 times the same values from TABLE_PAGES...But i want the values from TABLE_STATES

Answer (score 0):

> Currently this code goes to the same table TABLE_PAGES.

As far as I think, you should change `TABLE_PAGES` to `TABLE_STATES` in the following part of your code:

```
    elseif ($page_id <>"")
            {
                // On any other Page get the page id and fetch their related subpages
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_STATES . " WHERE parent = :parent";
                try
                {
                    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindValue(":parent", db_prepare_input($page_id));
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $pageResults = $stmt->fetchAll();
                }
                catch (Exception $ex)
                {
                    echo errorMessage($ex->getMessage());
                }
            }
```

I'm assuming you'll be running the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_STATES WHERE TABLE_STATES.page_id = TABLE_PAGES.page_id
```

which you can execute to get a list of all the states belonging to the **parent** (TABLE_PAGES) table.

***TIP:*** Always try to use table names that represent real-world entities AND serve the purpose of the actual data that you want to store. In your case `TABLE_COUNTRIES` would be a more conventional name for a table that represents the entity *country*.

You could also run a left join as such:

```
SELECT TABLE_STATES.* LEFT JOIN TABLE_COUNTRIES ON TABLE_COUNTRIES.page_id = TABLE_STATES.page_id AND TABLE_COUNTRIES.page_id = <your provided value>
```

Comment: the above code doesnot work as it says TABLE_PAGES.page_id is not defined...so i think we have to make a join. secondly, in the above code parent is passed as parameter...can you tell me from where parameter "parent" is coming?

Comment: Which code, yours or mine? You've stated that you have TABLE_PAGES.page_id column as well as TABLE_STATES.page_id column, which in your case can't be undefined.

Comment: in my code above i have changed table name to table_countries. when i run code all the countries are displayed with a link. I need this link to point to table_states and list all states which matches with current_page. like if link under USA is clicked then the next page should open all the states for USA(USA is current page)...this list should again contain a link which will point to table_county. can you please modify my code above...i am getting confused. need to join two tables upper part of <li> lists from table_country and below part <ahref should point to table_states. thanks for help

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, but I'm confused whether there is a **'parent'** (_without colon_) column in your table as you have in your SQL. I think it could have been **'page_id'**. Anyway you can achieve the same in a join as well (see the bottom of my answer).